# Left Join and Sum

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables, one that lists grants/loans and one that lists individual expenditures.  They share an ID column as each expenditure is assigned to a specific grant or loan.  I'm trying to use LEFT JOIN to sum the expenditures for all the loans combined, but not the grants.

Here's where I'm at:

```
SELECT SUM(expenses.total_amt) AS total 
FROM expenses WHERE loans_grants.grant_loan_type = 'Loan'
LEFT JOIN loans_grants
ON expenses.grant_loan_id = loans_grants.internal_id;
```

Any tips much appreciated!

Edit: thanks all, and apologies for the half baked question, it was late and I was in the weeds.

Here's the basic structures:

expenses:
[expenses table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JInJx.png)

loans_grants:
[loans_grants table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNsCr.png)

I've updated the code based on @jwood74's answer to this:

```
SELECT l.internal_id, SUM(e.total_amt) amount 
FROM loans_grants l 
LEFT JOIN expenses e ON e.grant_loan_id = l.internal_id
 WHERE grant_loan_type = 'Loan'
 group by l.internal_id
```

which produces this:

| internal id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3234 |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | 7625 |
| 7 | null |
| 9 | null |

Please excuse my noviceness, but I'm trying to sum up all expenses for loans, so I'd like to return 3234 + 7625, rather than summing expenses for each loan separately.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: First, this is not even a query.
Second, can you add more detail as, at least, table structure?

Comment: Hello! As per the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: WHERE clause must be placed after FROM clause (including JOIN clause which is a part of FROM).

Comment: A query in SQL starts with `SELECT`, so I'm baffled by your code.

Comment: Thanks all, and sorry for the half baked question.  I've edited it heavily based on your comments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a SINGLE ROW RETURNED, you do not need to do a group by anything... just the SUM() of what you are looking for.

Second, do not post pictures of your sample data and table structures.  Edit your original post and type the values in, even if you copy/paste the data and format it for readability (via Ctrl+K, or the curly brackets {} icon above post editing header area).

In this case, your tables

```
Loan_Grants table
Internal_id   grant_loan_type
1             Loan
2             Grant
3             Grant
4             Loan
5             Loan
6             Grant
7             Loan
8             Grant
9             Loan

Expenses Table
total_amt    grant_loan_id
2000         1
245          5
4500         5
2200         5
445          5
185          5
1234         1
50           5
```

Starting with your Loan_Grants table filtered on just your 'Loan' records

```
select
      sum( e.total_amt ) totalExpenses
   from
      loan_grants lg
         JOIN expenses e
            on lg.internal_id = e.grant_loan_id
   where
      lg.grant_loan_type = 'Loan'
```

You dont want a left-join unless you explicitly want to see ALL "Loan" entries, even if they have no expenses yet recorded.  By doing a regular (inner) JOIN, it means there MUST be a record in the expenses table.  Again, based on your needs.  If you have 10,000 loans and only 247 loans have expenses, do you want to see all 10,000 or just the 247 and what their totals are.  Since you are summarizing to a single return record, JOIN is your best choice here.

For future, ALWAYS try to apply a table.column or alias.column to all your fields so anyone assisting does not have to guess which table the column comes from.

Comment: thanks so much!  Really appreciate your help, and also the tips about how to format these questions - I'm new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact format of the two tables, it's a bit hard. But here would be the general idea-

```
select
   l.id,
   sum(e.amount) amount
from loans_grants l
left join expenses e on e.grant_loan_id = l.internal_id
where grant_loan_type = 'Loan'
group by l.id
```

Comment: Thanks @jwood74, you got me almost there! Edited the original question - your code gives me a sum of the expenses for each loan, but I'm hoping to return a single sum, for all the expenses for ANY loan.  Thanks for your help!